# Remove part of y-axis in a boxplot

Tags: r

For the following boxplot:

[image]

How can I modify the y-axis and remove the range 0.1 to 0.8? The reason I want to do so is that I want to make each boxplot clear (that start from the range of 0.81 - 1).

For this boxplot, I wrote the following R script:

```
dataset <- read.csv("/boxplot.csv")
x <- boxplot(dataset)
```

Comment: Try this: `boxplot(dataset, ylim=c(0.8, 1))`

Comment: @Dave2e The problem with this solution is that the lower values (in range 0.0 to 0.3) will be removed, which I don't want to remove.

Answer (score 0):

This is generally discouraged and considered bad practice, as it leads to misleading visualizations. But you can do this using `gap.boxplot()` from the package `plotrix`.

Here is an arbitrary example:

```
library(plotrix)

test_data <- c(rnorm(100, 1000, 20), 10, 20)

par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
boxplot(test_data, main = "boxplot")
gap.boxplot(test_data, gap = list(bottom = c(50, 900), top = c(NA, NA)),
            main = "gap.boxplot")
```

[image: example gapped boxplot]